# How to add 1 to a class using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jQuery and JS and I'm trying to make a dynamic menu. It's really simple. I gave two links a class "parent0" and "parent1". Instead of having to do this:

```
 $('parent0').hover(function(){

   $('child0').slideDown();

  });
 $('parent1').hover(function(){

   $('child1').slideDown();

  });
```

Is there a way that I can make it so jQuery adds 1 automatically each time?

i tried:

```
var count = 0;
var parent = $('.parent' + count++);
```

but I guess that doesn't really work...

Edit: See link: http://www.jsfiddle.net/zpGDV/1/

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't give them both the same CSS class?

Comment: Barry, I've added the link to the jsfiddle you posted in the comments below. This is pretty important information and you'll get much better responses if people can see the HTML.

Answer (score 2):

```
var count = 0;
function addMenu(){
  $('.parent'+count).hover(function(){
    $('.child'+count).slideDown();
  });
  count++;
}

addMenu();
addMenu();
```

*Really not sure what else you're intending to do here...*

Though I should mention you should not use class names for this sort of thing. Keep classes for general data, and use ID's for specific elements.

**EDIT**
Here's a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/f8tZC/) you can play with (and preview) of what I was referring to with classes versus ids.

Comment: i see, i might have to change from ul to divs to make this menu work

Answer (score 0):

try using [.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your HTML structure you might be able to just use the index (*if the parent links correspond in order to the child elements*).

**html**

```
<a href="" class="parent">link 1</a>
<a href="" class="parent">link 2</a>

<div class="child">child 1</div>
<div class="child">child 2</div>
```

**jquery**

```
$('.parent').hover(
     function(){
       $('.child').eq($(this).index()).slideDown();
     },
      function(){
       $('.child').eq($(this).index()).slideUp();
     }
 );
```

**demo**: http://www.jsfiddle.net/gaby/zpGDV/

Comment: @Barry have a look at http://www.jsfiddle.net/gaby/zpGDV/3/ or http://www.jsfiddle.net/gaby/zpGDV/4/ (i added `slideUp` to close it. otherwise they overlap..